# Tried calling: []("number")

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get a value from the realtime database and match it with the input given by a user. If it matches then, will navigate to the next page or else throw and error but in the part where i am implementing the method to get value from the realtime i am getting following error :

E/flutter (17592): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter (17592): Receiver: null
E/flutter (17592): Tried calling:

```dart
import 'package:country_code_picker/country_code_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'OTPController.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  DataSnapshot snapshot;

  Query _ref;
  String dialCodeDigits = "+977";
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 100),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.0, right: 28.0),
              child: Image.asset("assets/prologo.png"),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                "Phone (OTP) Authentication",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
              )),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 60,
              width: 400,
              child: CountryCodePicker(
                onChanged: (country) {
                  setState(() {
                    dialCodeDigits = country.dialCode;
                  });
                },
                initialSelection: "NPL",
                showCountryOnly: false,
                showOnlyCountryWhenClosed: false,
                favorite: ["+91", "IND", "+1", "USA"],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 10, left: 10),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Phone Number",
                      prefix: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                        child: Text(dialCodeDigits),
                      )),
                  maxLength: 12,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  controller: _controller,
                )),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  var numberPhone = dialCodeDigits + _controller.text;

                  FirebaseDatabase.instance
                      .reference()
                      .child('Subscribers')
                      .child('number')
                      .equalTo(numberPhone)
                      .once()
                      .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    Map numPhone = snapshot.value;
                    var phoneNumber = numPhone['number'];
                    print(phoneNumber);
                  });

                  if ('+917340868077' == numberPhone) {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (c) => OTPController(
                            phoneNumber: _controller.text,
                            codeDigit: dialCodeDigits)));
                  }
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Next',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is most likely occurs at this line:
`var phoneNumber = numPhone['number'];`

Since the `numPhone` is nullable, you can do a check like this:

```
//... other lines
.then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.value == null) {
    // do sth with the null return
    print('no data');
    return;
  }
  Map numPhone = snapshot.value;
  var phoneNumber = numPhone['number'];
  print(phoneNumber);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the think is that I do have values stored in the real-time database but I am not getting any of the values. As per the implementation you gave I am getting ‘no data’

Comment: @ashishrana Yes my above code is just for the initial error asked. Since it's a bit vague without looking at your DB, I think you should double-check the `.equalTo(numberPhone)` and see if the `numberPhone` is correctly formatted and exactly equal the value stored in Firebase